# how ptrace implemented in ARM

Tags: android, arm

I found that ptrace will use __ptrace and its code in __ptrace.S like below:

```
ENTRY(__ptrace)
.save   {r4, r7}
stmfd   sp!, {r4, r7}
ldr     r7, =__NR_ptrace
swi     #0
ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r7}
movs    r0, r0
bxpl    lr
b       __set_syscall_errno
END(__ptrace)
```

what I don't know is how the process continue at swi #0 and what r7 is doing here?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is performing a system call. When you run `swi #0`, control is handed back to the Linux kernel where it processes the request for ptrace.

A quick Google reveals the Linux kernel implementation is in [linux/kernel/ptrace.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c).

In the ARM EABI calling convention, r0-r3 are scratch registers and can be used as temporary registers. If you need to use any other register, you must save them. In this case, r7 is being used for holding the system call number `__NR_ptrace`. To use r7 without breaking the convention, it needs to be saved and restored when done.

In the code, that's done by:

```
...
stmfd   sp!, {r4, r7} /* Save */
ldr     r7, =__NR_ptrace /* Use */
...
ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r7} /* Restore */
...
```

This particular code is an **EABI** kernel [`syscall()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).  The slower older **OABI** uses `swi #__NR_ptrace` to signal the *function number* to the Linux kernel.  The `swi` instruction is [also known as `svc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459279/are-arm-instructuons-swi-and-svc-exactly-same-thing).  As per the **ARM** [documentation on `svc`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidabi.html), this instruction switches to *supervisor mode* and executes the *software interrupt* exception; at address [*0xffff0008* or *0x00000008*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215831/why-two-vector-table-addresses-on-arm).  The particular Linux code that handles this is in [*entry-armv.S*](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#L335).  It is not entirely clear why it is preserving `r4`.  The *function number* is sent to an **EABI** Linux in register `r7`, which indexes a table of `syscall()` Linux entry points.  Other familiar routines are `read()`, `write()`, etc.

Comment: thank you tangrs, so you mean the code to be executed is where __NR_ptrace pointed to? but how?

Comment: When control is handed back to the kernel, it will read r7 to determine which service the program requires.

Comment: actually I copied that piece of code from android. it there any doc for "reading r7 to decide service #"?

Comment: also I read the doc for SWI, seems it has 2 ways to pass arguments and swi #0 will use r0 as service number however in this case, r0 should be the request of ret = __ptrace(request, pid, addr, &word); and it confused me very much

Comment: The system call convention will probably be different for different operating systems. The one I'm talking about is the Linux kernel specifically (which Android runs on). The code for getting the syscall number can be found at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S#L387

Comment: ah, the code piece is using EABI, which defines the usage of r7 as service number. thanks much tangrs!

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually specified by the EABI. I think it's Linux specific TBH - might have to check up on it. Also, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it.