# remapping Interrupt vectors and boot block

Tags: arm, remap, lpc

I am not able to understand the concept of remapping Interrupt vectors or boot block. What is the use of remapping vector table? How it works with remap and without remap? Any links to good articles on this? I googled for this, but unable to get good answer. What is the advantage of mapping RAM to 0x0000 and mapping whatever existing in 0x0000 to elsewhere? Is it that execution is faster if executed from 0x0000?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why two vector table addresses on ARM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215831/why-two-vector-table-addresses-on-arm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a simple matter of practicality. The reset vector is at 0x0<sup>*</sup>, and when the system first powers up the core is going to start fetching instructions from there. Thus you have to have some code available there immediately from powerup - it's got to be some kind of ROM, since RAM would be uninitialised at this point. Now, once you've got through the initial boot process and started your application proper, you have a problem - your exception vectors, and the code to handle them, are in ROM! What if you want to install a different interrupt handler? What if you want to switch the reset vector for a warm-reset handler? By having the vector area remappable, the application is free to switch out the ROM boot firmware for the RAM area in which it's installed its own vectors and handler code.

Of course, this may not always be necessary - e.g. for a microcontroller running a single dedicated application which handles powerup itself - but as soon as you get into the more complex realm of separate bootloaders and application code it becomes more important. Performance is also a theoretical concern, at least - if you have slow flash but fast RAM you might benefit from copying your vectors and interrupt handlers into that RAM - but I think that's far less of an issue on modern micros.

Furthermore, if an application wants to be able to update the boot flash at runtime, then it absolutely needs a way of putting the vectors and handlers elsewhere. Otherwise, if an interrupt fires whilst the flash block is in programming mode, the device will lock up in a recursive hard fault due to not being able to read from the vectors, never finish the programming operation and brick itself.

Whilst most types of ARM core have some means to [change their own vector base address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9215831/3156750), some (like Cortex-M0), not to mention plenty of non-ARM cores, do not, which necessitates this kind of non-architecture-specific system-level remapping functionality to achieve the same result. In the case of microcontrollers built around older cores like ARM7TDMI, it's also quite likely for there to be no RAM behind the fixed alternative "high vectors" address (more suited for use withg an MMU), rendering that option useless.

<sub>* Yeah, OK, 0x4 if we're talking Cortex-M, but you know what I mean... ;)</sub>

Comment: Any links to understand more? Could not fully understand the boot process. I think first I need to understand the boot process and see what is executed from RAM and what is from ROM in case of embedded systems.